# Can't import FileExts key

Tags: windows-registry, regedit

I had to do a clean install of Windows 7 and exported `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts`

Now, when I try to import it - it seems to successfully import them via `regedit`, I can see the file types and associations in the registry, but when I click on the files they don't get opened by the corresponding programs.

Comment: Have you logged off and logged back on since doing the registry import?

Comment: Yes, I even restarted.

Answer (score 0):

HKEY_CURRENT_USER is not a real thing; it doesn't actually exist. It is a view that the Windows API gives to HKEY_USERS\Your-SID where Your-SID is the Security Id associated with the current user's account.

You can find the SID's of accounts by starting CMD and typing in

```
wmic useraccount get name, sid
```

Comment: I think the problem is that I also had to export the applications registry where the paths to each app are stored.